Error building Docker image for AWS Lambda function: Unable to install h5py due to missing HDF5 library
I'm trying to build a Docker image for an AWS Lambda function that requires the h5py library. However, I'm encountering an error related to missing HDF5 dependencies during the build process.
 => ERROR [4/6] RUN pip3 install h5py                                                                                                                                                                                               5.3s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 > [4/6] RUN pip3 install h5py:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0.346 Collecting h5py                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0.410   Downloading h5py-3.11.0.tar.gz (406 kB)                                                                                                                                                                                          
0.580   Installing build dependencies: started                                                                                                                                                                                           
4.652   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'                                                                                                                                                                       
4.652   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
4.774   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
4.775   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
4.895   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
5.014 Collecting numpy>=1.17.3 (from h5py)
5.014   Using cached numpy-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl.metadata (62 kB)
5.021 Using cached numpy-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (14.0 MB)
5.037 Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
5.038   Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml): started
5.199   Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
5.202   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
5.202   
5.202   × Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
5.202   │ exit code: 1
5.202   ╰─> [75 lines of output]
5.202       running bdist_wheel
5.202       running build
5.202       running build_py
5.202       creating build
5.202       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311
5.202       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py
5.202       copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py
5.202       copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py
5.202       copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py
5.202       copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py
5.202       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/_hl
5.202       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_completions.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_big_endian_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_file2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5pl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_file_alignment.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/conftest.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5z.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_getitem.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_errors.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_attribute_create.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_ros3.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5o.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_dataset_swmr.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_dtype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests
5.202       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
5.202       copying h5py/tests/data_files/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
5.202       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_virtual_source.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_highlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_vds/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
5.202       copying h5py/tests/test_vds/test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/test_vds
5.202       copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
5.202       copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
5.202       copying h5py/tests/data_files/vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/h5py/tests/data_files
5.202       running build_ext
5.202       Loading library to get build settings and version: libhdf5.so
5.202       error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
5.202       Library dirs checked: []
5.202       error: libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
5.202       [end of output]
5.202   
5.202   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
5.203   ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
5.203 Failed to build h5py
5.208 ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (h5py)
------
Dockerfile:17
--------------------
  15 |     
  16 |     # Install h5py with HDF5 support
  17 | >>> RUN pip3 install h5py
  18 |     
  19 |     # Copy function code
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install h5py" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

My Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# Install system dependencies
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y \
    python3-pip \
    pkgconfig \
    gcc \
    gcc-c++ \
    make \
    hdf5-devel \
    hdf5

# Update pip to the latest version
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Install h5py with HDF5 support
RUN pip3 install h5py

# Copy function code
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install additional dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]

requirements.txt
pymongo
python-dotenv
Pillow
boto3
Flask
flask-cors
numpy
deepface

docker build command -
docker build --no-cache --platform linux/arm64 -t picalive-backend-dev .

I am using Apple M2 to build this image.
Despite many efforts, I have still not successfully built the Docker image for my Lambda function. What additional steps can I take to resolve this issue and ensure that h5py is installed correctly with the required HDF5 dependencies?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Verify Library Location:

Locate libhdf5.so:  Inside your Docker image, use the command locate libhdf5.so to find the actual location of the library file.
Check LD_LIBRARY_PATH:  If locate shows the file, ensure that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable includes the directory where it resides.  You can use the echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH command to verify this.

If the library isn't found automatically, you might need to provide explicit linking during the pip3 install h5py step:
     RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/lib64" --global-option="-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial" h5py
 

--no-cache-dir prevents issues with cached builds.
- -L/usr/lib64 tells the compiler where to look for libraries. You might need to adjust the path if libhdf5.so is located elsewhere.
- -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial tells the compiler where to find the necessary header files.
